# Third monitor with AMD cards WITHOUT Eyefinity

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have two AMD Radeon HD 6870 video cards in CrossFireX configuration and I would like to add a third monitor. I understand to use "Eyefinity" you need to use an active mini displayport to DVI adapter. I am not interested in the benefits of "Eyefinity", I just want a third monitor with Windows extended desktop.

Is it possible to use either the HDMI head on the first card or the DVI heads from the second card to get a third monitor running without "Eyefinity" and an active adapter?

Comment: It should work OK. Just grab a monitor from one of your friends and test it out, before you make a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used a Plugable UGA-2K-A USB 2.0 Video Card to have 5 total monitors on a machine. This was for work, so I wasn't gaming, so it may/may not perform for what you'll need.

[Amazon link - $64 [not a referral link]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038P1TP4)